# Viewing images from IP cameras

Tags: opencv, python

I am writing through a translator

I have a code

```
import cv2

stream = cv2.VideoCapture('protocol://IP:port/1') 

while True:
    r, f = stream.read()
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

if I could not get the stream from the camera but I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Proge\good2.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

How to add a check whether the image is received or is it empty?

Or something like that to avoid mistakes

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error message, though cryptic, is telling you that `f` is `None`. It is wise to check `r` ("retVal" in the documentation) to verify that the `read()` succeeded. Change the code inside the loop to something like

```
r, f = stream.read()
if r:
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera Stream, f)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Now if your code is actually using `'protocol://IP:port/1'`, then that'll be cause of the issue. `protocol`, `IP`, and `port` are all placeholder for parts that you'll need to provide. (And depending on the camera, you might need to provide an account name and password. A full URL will look something like

```
'rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.10:554/11'
```